# TYPO3 - Indexed Search and how to index extension

Tags: search, typo3, realurl

I use indexed_search and RealUrl and I need it to show the whole url in the search result.

Right now it is only showing that part of the url which is related to pages and not the part that is related to my extension.

Now it shows: domain.dk/products/

But it should show: domain.dk/products/product/product-title

I dont know whether it is in RealUrl configuration or in Indexed Search I should make som changes.

Comment: I'm not sure if indexed_search covers custom extensions at all? If it does index your content and does return it in the results, maybe you want to post your config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some pretty good explanations on the web, showing how to index database/extension records with the crawler extension. Try [this one](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html#c863) as a start, it shows everything step by step and with screenshots, so I guess it should be useful.

If this is not enough, there are ready-to-use examples for tt_news and other extensions in the [crawler documentation](http://wiki.typo3.org/Crawler#example_set_of_crawler_configurations).